# How to install wkhtmltopdf 0.12.1 on Ubuntu server?

Tags: apt, software-installation, wkhtmltopdf

I am trying to install current stable version `0.12.1`, but it only installs `0.9.9`.
Any chance to install latest version with `apt-get install`? It seems that `0.9.9` is **very old** :(

Comment: See also: [How can I install the latest wkhtmltopdf on Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/q/959152/10425)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In Ubuntu 16.04 and later wkhtmltopdf 0.12.2+ can be installed from the default Ubuntu repositories.

In Ubuntu 14.04, open the terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ecometrica/servers
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf
```

In Ubuntu 12.04, open the terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pov/wkhtmltopdf
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf
```

and one step after this is to reboot the server or else you will get the error: `wkhtmltopdf: cannot connect to X server` .

Comment: Just tried the 12.04 instructions, wasn't able to successfully download from the PPA: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pov/wkhtmltopdf/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

Comment: The links at ppa:pov/wkhtmltopdf are live. I was able to download the .deb file of wkhtmltopdf for Ubuntu 12.04 from it manually from: https://launchpad.net/~pov/+archive/ubuntu/wkhtmltopdf/+sourcepub/4571508/+listing-archive-extra

Comment: (Using v0.12.0-2 from ppa:ecometrica/servers on Ubuntu Server 14.04) I still get "Cannot connect to X server" unless I use xvfb as described in http://askubuntu.com/a/605644/7146

Comment: is ecometrica/servers still maintained? I was not able to find an up to date ppa for 0.12.2 (Jan 15) anywhere on launchpad

Comment: @Steve The latest version of wkhtmltopdf, last updated on 7/10/2014, is wkhtmltopdf 0.12.0-2 at this ppa:pov/wkhtmltopdf webpage: https://launchpad.net/~ecometrica/+archive/ubuntu/servers?field.series_filter=trusty

Answer (score 34):

Steps:

1. At first install xvfb serwer:

   ```sh
   sudo apt-get install xvfb
   ```
2. Get needed version of wkhtmltopdf from http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html.

   For Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit:

   ```sh
   wget http://download.gna.org/wkhtmltopdf/0.12/0.12.2.1/wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
   ```
3. Install wkhtmltopdf:

   ```sh
   sudo dpkg -i wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
   ```

   Install dependency (if needed):

   ```sh
   sudo apt-get -f install
   ```
4. Create symblic link in `/usr/local/bin/`:

   ```sh
   echo 'exec xvfb-run -a -s "-screen 0 640x480x16" wkhtmltopdf "$@"' | sudo tee /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf.sh >/dev/null
   sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf.sh
   ```

Comment: Thank you for this. I didn't realize the issue I was having was I needed xvfb to run wkhtmltopdf headless. Works like a charm.

Comment: Please be informed that `gna.org` has been closed now. so you should download precompiled binaries from https://downloads.wkhtmltopdf.org . Please see
https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/3390#issuecomment-287982282

Comment: It worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

I used the following on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

```
wget http://download.gna.org/wkhtmltopdf/0.12/0.12.2/wkhtmltox-0.12.2_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install libxrender1 xfonts-utils xfonts-base xfonts-75dpi libfontenc1 x11-common xfonts-encodings libxfont1 fontconfig
sudo dpkg -i wkhtmltox-0.12.2_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
sudo reboot now
```

**Note:** this is version **0.12.2**! So you don't have to deal with installing xvfb since you're probably not running X as it's a server.

If it fails at `sudo dpkg -i wkhtmltox-0.12.2_linux-trusty-amd64.deb` then proceed with `sudo apt get install -f` to install with dependencies.

Comment: This is very similar to [Pavels' answer](/a/605644/175814) except that you suggest to install the dependency packages *manually* which prevents their later auto-removal once they cease to be in use. -1

Comment: @DavidFoerster it is similar, but the newer version number doesn't require xvfb which is the main difference. I don't think the downvote was necessary.

Answer (score 0):

To install wkhtmltopdf 0.12.5 on ubuntu 16.04, try this,

1. Wkhtmltopdf version 0.12.5 is recommended for odoo 12.

   ```
   wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.5/wkhtmltox_0.12.5-1.trusty_amd64.deb
   ```
2. Install the package using DPKG.

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i wkhtmltox_0.12.5-1.trusty_amd64.deb
   ```
3. This will install all dependencies.

   ```
   sudo apt -f install
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Solution :

1. Download the [deb archive](https://downloads.wkhtmltopdf.org/0.12/0.12.1/wkhtmltox-0.12.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb) and install using DPKG.

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i wkhtmltox-0.12.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
   ```
2. ```
   sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/bin
   ```
3. ```
   sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage /usr/bin
   ```

Answer (score -1):

After trying the below command, It worked for me

```
cd ~
yum install -y xorg-x11-fonts-75dpi xorg-x11-fonts-Type1 openssl git-core fontconfig
wget https://downloads.wkhtmltopdf.org/0.12/0.12.4/wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz
tar xvf wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz
mv wkhtmltox/bin/wkhtmlto* /usr/bin
```