# How to install wkhtmltopdf, specifically v0.12.4 in ubuntu server 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, apt, software-installation, ppa, wkhtmltopdf

I know there is already a [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/556667/how-to-install-wkhtmltopdf-0-12-1-on-ubuntu-server) regarding `wkhtmltopdf` installation, but I need the specific version 0.12.4 to be installed. Is there a way to do it .

Normal apt-get installation ended up in v0.12.0

Is there any ppa repositories which is maintained for this version. I don't see it in [this](https://launchpad.net/%7Epov/+archive/ubuntu/wkhtmltopdf/+sourcepub/4571508/+listing-archive-extra)

Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer with help of `wkhtmltopdf` authors in [github](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/3929)

```
apt-get update 
apt-get install -y --force-yes xvfb 
wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.4/wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz 
tar xvf wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz 
mv wkhtmltox/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/bin 
rm wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz  && rm -rf wkhtmltox
```

Thanks to [ashkulz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2536643/ashkulz)